# In crontab i write 10 15 7,23 * Thu /home/ravikant/script1 . Is it run twice when 7 or 23 date is Thu?

Tags: server, cron

In crontab I wrote `10 15 7,23 * Thu /home/ravikant/script1`. Is it run twice when 7 or 23 date is Thu?

```
10 15 7,23 * Thu /home/ravikant/script1
```

I want to run script on 7 and 23 as well as every Thursday so I write above line to execute the script. Is it run twice or not.

Answer (score 0):

If day-of-month and day-of-week are both a match, the job is still executed only once.

See also [`10 15 7,23 * Thu`](https://crontab.guru/#10_15_7,23_*_Thu)